# Probability of 3rd card between 1st two

Tags: probability

From a random deck, 1 card is drawn, then another. Then without replacement a 3rd card is drawn. What is the probability that the 3rd card is between the 1st two.

Comment: What is in the deck and what does it mean to be "between"?  Is it a standard 52-card deck, or a Pinochle deck, or an abstract set of cards numbered $1$ through $n$, or perhaps something else?  Would a two be between a Jack and an Ace or not?  Would a two be between a two and a three or not?

Answer (score 3):

@wythagoras is absolutely correct if there is a hierarchy of suites

However, if pairs are considered equal, then the odds drop a little.

The odds of getting 3 unique values are:

$$p_{no pair}=\frac{48}{51}*\frac{44}{50}\approx0.828$$

multiply this by the 1/3 from above and the odds are:

$$p=p_{nopair}*p_{right order}=0.828*0.333\approx0.276$$

Comment: There are $6$ permutations of these $3$ unique cards, are you certain the last probability should be $1/3$?

Comment: @JohnK Yes, since it doesn't matter in which order the first two cards are drawn.

Comment: @JohnK, yup, since 2 of those 6 permutations are what we are looking for we get $\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like the following.

Suppose the cards $A, B$ and $C$ are drawn, not yet in a determined order.

Assume without loss of generality that in your ordering of cards, card $A$ comes before card $B$, and card $B$ comes before card $C$.

- If card $B$ is drawn last, then it it between $A$ and $C$.
- If card $A$ is drawn last, then it it not between $B$ and $C$.
- If card $C$ is drawn last, then it it not between $A$ and $B$.

Each event is equally likely, so the probability that they are in order is $\frac13$.

Comment: This is incorrect and does not consider the case when cards are of the same number.  It also is unclear as to what "comes before" means. Do you mean chronologically or numerically?

Comment: @MattBrems The cards are drawn without replacement.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you could draw a 4 of Hearts and a 4 of Spades.

Comment: But then the question is unclear, because I meant something else with between, namely some card order, so for example a 4 of Spades is better than a 4 of Hearts. With "comes before" I meant using this order.